# Rapidly binning 3D data

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, histograms

I have a set of data (about 20 million datapoints for my real data) of the form `{x, y, z, m}`. There are 3 spatial coordinates `x`, `y` and `z` and a fourth value, the mass (`m`) of the element at that point.

I want to bin the data onto a integer spaced 3D grid. And then bin the masses into a series of specific ranges. I want the number of masses that fall into each mass range for each point on the grid. I guess, for `n` ranges I will need `n` 3D arrays or alternatively a 3D array where each point has a list of `n` values.

Let's start with some random data

```
coords = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10^5, 3}]; (*these can be negative*)
masses = RandomReal[400, 10^5]; (*these can't be negative*)
```

and some random ranges to bin the masses, we'll make 50 as this is about how many I have in my real data:

```
ranges = Partition[Union[Round[RandomReal[400, 100], 0.001]], 2];
```

Based on this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178714/mathematica-fast-2d-binning-algorithm. I started by rounding the coordinates, I want to bin onto unit bins so I simply used `Floor` on the coordinates.

```
indices = Floor[coords];
```

and in my case the masses have more precision than the mass range specifications so lets round those now too.

```
roundedmass = Round[masses, 0.001];
```

Now based on the related question I used `GatherBy` to collect like coordinates into lists.

```
gathered = GatherBy[Transpose[{indices, roundedmass}], First];
```

However, I'm stuck as to how to quickly bin the masses in each of the gathered coordinate-bins into the various mass ranges. In the end I guess I will have 50 3D arrays where each coordinate-bin has a value corresponding to the number of masses in the specified mass-range. 50 mass ranges = 50 3D arrays (probably sparse as there will be lots of empty space), or alternatively a 3D array where each point has a list of 50 values.

I've tried to use `BinCounts` but this also bins in between the mass ranges so I had to drop ever other bin that was returned, seems wasteful...:

```
fbinmasses = BinCounts[#, {Flatten@ranges}][[;; ;; 2]] &
binnedmass = ParallelMap[fbinmasses, gathered[[All, All, 2]]]; 
combinedoutput = Transpose[{gathered[[All, 1, 1]], binnedmass}];
sortedoutput = Sort[combinedoutput, OrderedQ[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}] &];
```

Now, I would need to make a sparse array, maybe like this (going to have issues with negative inidices...? And it seems like you can't store a list in a sparse array.

```
output = SparseArray[gathered[[All, 1, 1]] -> binnedmass]
```

Comment: I think `binnedmasses` should be `binnedmass` in the `combinedoutput` calculation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading over your post it seems that there are two problems you're having trouble with:

1. How to bin lists of numbers into bins that may not be consecutive
2. How to represent the output of your calculation

To address #2 first, I think your idea to use a 3D `SparseArray`, where each element is a list of mass bin counts, is a good one. As you found, and as the documentation points out, the values of a `SparseArray` can't be lists, but we could just replace the `Head` of a list with some other dummy symbol like `MassCounts` to get this working. So the problem is to create a list of array rules that looks like this:

```
{ ... , {xIndex,yIndex,zIndex} -> MassCounts[m1, m2, ... , m50] , ...}
```

To address question #1, you already suggest a solution in your post (`BinCounts[#, {Flatten@ranges}][[;; ;; 2]]`). Another way to do this would be to write a new BinCounts function that can deal with non-consecutive bins, like this:

```
ClearAll[BinCountsNC];
BinCountsNC[xs_, bins_] :=
 With[{
   lowerEdges = First@Transpose@Sort[bins],
   upperEdges = Last@Transpose@Sort[bins]},

  (Thread[lowerEdges <= # < upperEdges] & /@ xs) //
    Boole //
   Total
  ]
```

In the timings below you can see that this alternative is significantly faster than your initial solution, which was a surprise to me, but there it is.

To make it a bit easier to construct the sparse array rules, I also just added `101` to all the coordinates. Putting everything together, we've got

```
coords = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10^5, 3}]; (*these can be negative*)
masses = RandomReal[400, 10^5]; (*these can't be negative*)

ranges = Partition[Union[Round[RandomReal[400, 100], 0.001]], 2];

indices = Floor[coords] + 101;

roundedmass = Round[masses, 0.001];

gathered = GatherBy[Transpose[{indices, roundedmass}], First];

In[141]:= 
rules = 
  Map[
   #[[1, 1]] -> MassCounts @@ BinCounts[#[[All, -1]], List@Flatten@ranges][[;; ;; 2]] &, 
   gathered]; // Timing

Out[141]= {140.941, Null}

In[142]:= 
rules2 = 
  Map[
   #[[1, 1]] -> MassCounts @@ BinCountsNC[#[[All, -1]], ranges] &, 
   gathered]; // Timing

Out[142]= {10.3167, Null}
```

The two methods produce the same results:

```
rules == rules2 (* -> True *)
```

And you can construct a `SparseArray` using either of these sets of rules:

```
array = SparseArray[rules];
array[[Sequence @@ (array // ArrayRules // First // First)]]
(* -> MassCounts[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178714/mathematica-fast-2d-binning-algorithm) to speed things up considerably.  `UnitStep` and `Rescale` are used to mark the ranges in which a mass lies, `1` if in, `0` if not.  Then `SparseArray` is used as in the linked answer to add up the marks.

**The set up.**

```
SeedRandom[1];
coords = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10^5, 3}]; (*these can be negative*)
masses = RandomReal[400, 10^5]; (*these can't be negative*)
ranges = Partition[Union[Round[RandomReal[400, 100], 0.001]], 2];
roundedmass = Round[masses, 0.001];
```

**The solution.**

Not compiling `unitMark` takes almost 50% longer.  The key to efficient speed and memory usage is keeping [arrays packed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).

Some comments to explain the code:

1. `unitMark[x]` is `1` when `0 <= x < 1`; the masses `roundedmass` are rescaled for each range so that they lie in this interval exactly when the mass is between end points of the range, i.e, in $[min, max)$.
2. The form of `nzpos` is `{{rangesindex, roundedmassindex}, ..}`.
3. The output has the form `bincounts[[x, y, z, m]]`, where `x, y, z, m` are the indices and the value is the numbers of masses lying in the bin `{x, y, z, m}`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 indices = Floor[coords + 101];
 unitMark = Compile[{{masses, _Real, 2}}, UnitStep[masses] - UnitStep[masses - 1], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
 nzpos = SparseArray[unitMark[Rescale[roundedmass, #, {0, 1}] & /@ ranges]][
   "NonzeroPositions"];
 nzindices = Transpose[ Transpose @ indices[[Last /@ nzpos]] ~Append~ (First /@ nzpos) ];
 SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
 bincounts = SparseArray[nzindices -> 1];
 SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
 ]
(* {0.333861, Null} *)
```

By comparison, the timings I got with [DGrady](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/428)'s two methods
were
`80.025997`
and
`6.249729`
seconds.

Example: Here are the indices for the bins with a "high" count.

```
Cases[ArrayRules[bincounts], HoldPattern[_ -> _?(# > 1 &)], Infinity]
(* {{ 53,  65, 105, 48} -> 2, { 61, 28, 173, 28} -> 2,
    { 68,  60,  46, 50} -> 2, {165, 30, 129, 50} -> 2,
    {198, 174,  56, 40} -> 2}   *)
```

**Check**

It's a little tricky because of the difference in the ways the counts are stored in the two solutions.  In `array` the entries are either `0` representing all 50 counts are zero or `MassCounts[c1, c2, ...]`; sometimes all the `c1`, `c2`, etc.

```
If[(Normal@bincounts /. {0 ..} -> 0) == (Normal@array /. 
     MassCounts[0 ..] -> 0 /. MassCounts -> List),
 True, False, "huh?"]
(* True *)
```

There's a difference in memory usage too.

```
ByteCount /@ {bincounts, array}
(* {1434688, 126416264} *)
```